# Can't parse image with jsoup android

Tags: android, image, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm training with parsing news site. I've got some problems with parsing image.

http://www.ua-football.com/ - `class="stripe-container`

Code from `MainActivity.class`

```
         @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("\"Mozilla/5.0      (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();
            for (Element container : doc.select("div[class=stripe-container]")){
                for (Element ul_li : container.select("ul li")){
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    Elements img_src = ul_li.select("img[src]");
                        String img = img_src.attr("src");
                        System.out.println(img);
                    //map.put("logo", img);
                    map.put("text", ul_li.text());
                    map.put("logo",img);
                    arraylist.add(map);


                }
            }



        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And `getView` from `Adapter`

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text_of_news;
    ImageView logo;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    text_of_news = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_of_news);
    logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    text_of_news.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TEXT_OF_NEWS));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.LOGO), logo);



    return itemView;
}
```

After opening app I can see the text, but instead of required images I find default `image` from the `ImageLoader`

Where is my fail?

Comment: Are you updating the Adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @MatousHybl shoud I do it in the method, where I declare Adapter (onPostExecute)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't parse image with jsoup android

To get the images `src`, you may be looking for something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ua-football.com/").timeout(30000).get();
Elements imgs = doc.getElementsByClass("stripe-container").select("img");
for (Element img : imgs) {      
   String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
   System.out.println(imgSrc);
}
```

---

**STDOUT**

```
http://www.ua-football.com/img/upload/17/21ef0d.jpeg
http://www.ua-football.com/img/upload/17/21d43e.jpeg
http://www.ua-football.com/img/upload/16/2174cb.jpeg
etc...
```

---

Read more about [jsoup dom-navigation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)